# Unknown option in node querystring library

Tags: node.js

The parse module in querystring lib lists the following.

> querystring.parse(str[, sep[, eq[, options]]])

I've also seen the following code

> const { parse } = require('querystring')
>
> ...
>
> let actual = parse(queryString)[queryStringPropName]

Why is the array appended after parse(queryString) and more importantly, why does it work?

The array-appending was not seen in querystring's [API page](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) in NodeJS.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because parse(queryString) is an object and in this case, [queryStringPropName] is not an array, it is to access a prop of the object parse(queryString)